# c# to PHP SQL Injection Prevention

Tags: c#, php, security, mysqli, sql-injection

i have a simple Script to send a SQL Query to a PHP Script, but I do not know how I can protect it from SQL Injection.

Do you have an idea ? Thanks!

C# Script

```
private void SQLConnect()
{
string urlAddress = "XXX";
```

Query for the PHP Script

```
string query = "INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ('Test-Name')";
```

Send the Query via POST to the PHP Script

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection()
{
{ "newQuery", query },
};
string pagesource = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(urlAddress, postData));
}
}
```

PHP Script

```
$db_server = xxx;
$db_benutzer = 'xxx';
$db_passwort = 'xxx';
$db_name = 'xxx';
```

Connect to Database

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_server, $db_benutzer, $db_passwort, $db_name);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit();
} 
else
{
echo "Connected...\n";
}
```

Receive and Execute the Query from C#

```
$newQuery = $_POST["newQuery"];;

if ($mysqli->query($newQuery) === TRUE) 
{
echo("Success...\n");
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: It depends is your query generated by sources that you don't trust? If its only about the variables that are generated by untrusted sources you can use the answer of Ronald.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the variables. So in your post you have a query with placeholders: INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES @p1

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection()
    {
        { "newQuery", query },
        { "P1", username }
    };
}
```

Then you use PHP to safely replace the parameters: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php